# Responsive Padding Trouble

Tags: css, responsive-design, width, media-queries, padding

I designed a responsive web page for tutorial and I have a trouble with unnecessary padding.

http://zinzinzibidi.com/res

In this page when you decrease the your browser window resolution, you will see the horizontal scroll bar (overflow-x) in some resolutions. I am trying to understand but I can't fix this trouble for a few days.

Here is an example picture of my trouble:

[image]

My CSS codes here: http://zinzinzibidi.com/Areas/res/Content/css/style.css

My media screen codes are

[image: My CSS codes]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that an inner item is causing the issue. Remove the padding from #header-main-buffer and it should go away.

line 515 of your file:

```
#header-main-buffer {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 10px; <- this is your problem. remove it and it will be fixed
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine now. You can check it out. By the way, how did you notice the problem? 300px width and 10px right + 10px left padding were responsive with 320px media screen width (?)

Comment: #head-container has the exact same width and padding so its inside elements are going to start to the right by the 10px the padding is adding to it. You really could have gotten rid of the padding on #head-container and it should have worked as well, its just the buffer item seemed more convenient to me.

Comment: You also could avoid situations like this in the future by setting `box-sizing: border-box;` you should look into that ([link explaining borderbox](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)) because it will cause the padding to go inside the elements width, so you would actually write it like this `width: 100%; padding: 0 10px; box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it might be your `<div id="header-logo">` the one creating that extra padding.

Since the `img` has a fixed width of 300px on screens smaller than tit will create an extra padding to the right so it fits the screen.

Try reducing the

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 320px) {
 #header-container {
  width:;
 }
}
```

EDIT

---

Basically check all the `img` that you're using so you make sure their width is appropriate and they fit the screen.

Comment: This problem has also in other media screens. So that's not about image resolution.